# How to handle connect method in node's http-proxy to allow websocket connection through the proxy?

Tags: node.js, websocket, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to make an HTTP proxy server using `node-http-proxy` module but I also want to support WebSocket in my proxy server. For that, I have registered an event listener on the `upgrade` method like following code which is working perfectly if I pass my local proxy server's URL to agent key of WebSocket

```
httpServer.on("upgrade", function(req, sock, head) {
    console.log("upgrade called")

    let reqUrl = req.url
    let hostPath = reqUrl.split("//")[1]
    let wsUrl = `ws://${hostPath}`

    proxy.ws(req,sock,head, {
            target: wsUrl,
            ws: true,
            autoRewrite: true,
            changeOrigin: true
    })
})
```

But when I use my local proxyServer's URL in google-chrome as HTTP proxy URL and then try to use any WebSocket code then it does not call upgrade method of my proxy, instead, chrome calls connect method. So I also listen on the `connect` method of my HTTP server and wrote the same code with little modification in connect method's callback. You can see my code below

```
httpServer.on("connect", (req, clientSocket, head) => {
    console.log("connect called")

    let reqUrl = req.url
    let wsUrl = `ws://${reqUrl}`

    proxy.ws(req,clientSocket,head,
        {
            target: wsUrl,
            ws: true,
            autoRewrite: true,
            changeOrigin: true
        })
})
```

But still, my proxy doesn't work for WebSockets. If I try running var `ws=new WebSocket('ws://echo.websocket.org/');` in browser console then I get the following error `WebSocket connection to 'ws://echo.websocket.org/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` This time connect method was called with no error on the server side but client's WebSocket is not connected

So I want to know, how do I handle the `connect` method to allow WebSocket connection through my proxy